# Getting confused with == and = in "if" statement

Tags: java, compiler-errors, scjp

I know that we cant use assignment operator in if statements in java as we use in any other few languages.

that is

```
            int a;

            if(a = 1) {  }
```

will give a compilation error.

but the following code works fine, how?

```
           boolean b;

           if(b = true) {   }
```

EDIT : Is this the exception to rule that assignment cant be used in if statement.

Comment: It's not a bad idea to get in the habit of putting the constant first in your if statements....
That is:
if (true == b) {}  and
if (1 == a) {}

This habit guarantees that the compiler will smack you if you write = instead of ==.

Comment: @Ollie: opinions widely differ on that one. As far as readability is concerned, this *is* a bad idea. Furthermore, it offers no benefit in languages such as Java since no confusion can arise here. I mean, nobody ever writes a test as `if (a == true)`, right?

Comment: @Konrad.  You're right in Java, but for this C retread who works in PERL and some other languages, it's saved me lots of times.

Comment: Doesn't work in a huge variety of cases, like `if ( $a == $b )`. Horrible to read, nobody says '5 is a'. It's easier to just be more careful when writing `if` conditions, IMO.

Comment: @Ollie most compilers these days have an option to warn you if you write `if(foo = x)` or something like that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Because the "result" of an assignment is the value assigned... so it's still a `boolean` expression in the second case. `if` expressions require the condition to be a `boolean` expression, which is satisfied by the second but not the first. Effectively, your two snippets are:

```
int a;

a = 1;
if (a) { }
```

and

```
boolean b;

b = true;
if (b) { }
```

Is it clear from that expansion that the second version will compile but not the first?

This is one reason not to do comparisons with true and false directly. So I would always just write `if (b)` instead of `if (b == true)` and `if (!b)` instead of `if (b == false)`. You still get into problems with `if (b == c`) when `b` and `c` are `boolean` variables, admittedly - a typo there can cause an issue. I can't say it's ever happened to me though.

EDIT: Responding to your edit - assignments of all kinds can be used in `if` statements - and `while` loops etc, so long as the overall condition expression is `boolean`. For example, you might have:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    // Do something with a line
}
```

While I *usually* avoid side-effects in conditions, this particular idiom is often useful for the example shown above, or using `InputStream.read`. Basically it's "while the value I read is useful, use it."

Comment: Are you sure there are an extra pair of parentheses in the last example? I thought assignment has the last precedence in Java...

Comment: @Carlos: Good catch. Maybe I'm so used to deliberately putting it in that I've never tried without :)

Comment: I usually think of that idiom (and use it when the analogy fits) in terms of the iterator's hasNext and next methods - it's basically implementing a combination of those for something that isn't explicitly an iterator (and I sure wish readers had implementation of that interface added in later versions).

Comment: Additionally, in some languages (C, C++) an integer can be substituted for a boolean value, with 0 being false and non-0 being true. Which widely increases the chances of the =/== bug.

Comment: @mtruesdell: Indeed, although I believe most C and C++ compilers will warn you unless you have an extra pair of parentheses to reinforce that it's deliberate... at least if you have warnings turned up high enough.

Comment: You can avoid the danger of if(b == c) by instead using something like if(!(b ^ c)).

Comment: @ILMTitan: Yes, but if you're thinking enough about it to write that, chances are you'll get it right anyway :)

Answer (score 10):

For `if` you need an expression that evaluates to *boolean*. `b = true` evalueates to *boolean* but `a = 1` evaluates to *int* as assignments always evaluate to the assigned values.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the second code works okay is because it is assigning 'b' the value of true, and then comparing to see if b is true or false.  The reason you can do this is because you can do assignment operators inside an if statement, AND you can compare against a boolean by itself.  It would be the same as doing if(true).

Answer (score 1):

In java, you don't have implicit casting. So non-boolean values or not automatically transformed to booleans.

In the first case, the result of the statements is an int, which is non-boolean, which will not work. The last case, the result is boolean, which can be evaluated in an if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is not that "assignment can't be used in an `if` statement", but that "the condition in an `if` statement must be of type `boolean`". An assignment expression produces a value of the type being assigned, so Java only permits assignment in an `if` statement if you're assigning a `boolean` value.

This is a good reason why the style `if (foo == true)` should be avoided, and instead simply write `if (foo)`.