# java equivalent of Delphi NOT

Tags: java, delphi, if-statement, boolean-logic

In Delphi I can do the following with a boolean variable:

```
If NOT bValue then
begin
  //do some stuff
end;
```

Does the equivalent in Java use the !?

```
If !(bValue) {
  //do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but inside the bracket:

```
if (!bValue) {
}
```

You'd normally not use any sort of data type prefix in Java as well, so it would more likely be something like:

```
if (!isGreen) { // or some other meaningful variable name
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  My variable is actually IsFYE so it is meaningful!

Comment: BTW: Using data type prefixes isn't common practice in Delphi either. More common are prefixes that identify the scope of a variable which I generally find much more useful, too.

Answer (score 10):

You're close; the proper syntax is:

```
if (!bValue) {
  //do some stuff
}
```

The entire conditional expression must be inside the parenthesis; the condition in this case involve the unary logical complement operator `!` ([JLS 15.15.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.15.6)).

Additionally, Java also has the following logical binary operators:

- [JLS 15.22.2 Boolean Logical Operators `&`, `^` and `|`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.2)

  - casually "and", "xor" and "or"
- [JLS 15.23 Conditional-and `&&`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.23) and [JLS 15.24 Conditional-or `||`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.24)

  - the *much more frequently used* short-circuiting "and" and "or"

There are also compound assignment operators ([JLS 15.26.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2)) `&=`, `|=`, `^=`.

---

#### Other relevant questions on stackoverflow:

- [Shortcut "or-assignment" (|=) operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486472/shortcut-or-assignment-operator-in-java/2486574#2486574)
- [Why doesn’t Java have compound assignment versions of the conditional-and and conditional-or operators? (&&=, ||=)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324549/why-doesnt-java-have-compound-assignment-versions-of-the-conditional-and-and-con)
- [What’s the difference between | and || in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96667/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-java)
- [Cleanest way to toggle a Boolean variable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224311/cleanest-way-to-toggle-a-boolean-variable-in-java)
- [Getting confused in with == and = in “if” statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393988/getting-confused-in-with-and-in-if-statement)

  - There are plenty of similar questions on stackoverflow due to accidental boolean assignment instead of comparison
  - You never need to write `== true` and `== false`

    - Omit explicit comparison with `true` and `false`
    - use `!` when necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!bValue) {
    // do some stuff
}
```