# how to check whether row exists or not in a table of sqlite for android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to check whether a row of the sqlite table exists in database or not..If row exists i should call a class otherwise another class.To get this functionality i am using

```
  public boolean Exists(int position) {

       SQLiteDatabase db =  (placeData).getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from pages where bbookid ='"+ position +"'", null);

       boolean exists = (cursor.getColumnName(position)) != null;
       Log.i("logs","fads");
       if(exists=true)
       {
           getDataAndPopulate();
       }
       else
       {
       Log.i("qefw","cursors");
       new LoadAllProducts().execute();
       }
       cursor.close();
       return exists;
    }
```

but using this code the rows are reinserting ..Could anyone suggest me the way to approach the functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equality check is failing because this expression is evaluating to `true`:

```
if(exists=true)
```

When you have a single equals sign, it means *assignment*. You are assigning `true` to `exists`, instead of comparing `exists` to `true`. The result of the assignment is the value to which `exists` was assigned (`true`).

Try the proper equality operator instead:

```
if (exists == true)
```

See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393988/getting-confused-with-and-in-if-statement) for another look at this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is in if(exists=true). Need to change to if (exists == true).
You can also check using cursor.getCount(); It will returns the numbers of rows in the cursor