# Java vs Python Logic on Selection Statement( if-else)

Tags: python

In JAVA the below code gives output as "hi"

```
boolean b=True;
if (b=False) 
{ 
    SOP("hello"); 
} 
else 
{ 
    SOP("hi"); 
}
```

The same login in Python-2.7 does not work. Why???????

```
b=True
if (b=False):
        print "hello"
else:
        print "hi"
```

Comment: your syntax is wrong.Use == for compare

Comment: Try if (b): print "hello" else: print "hi" .

Comment: `f"h{('i','ello')[b]}"`

Comment: The question is wrong. The check for equality in `if` statement for both languages is `==` not a single "=". Vote to close this question.

Comment: But when it "=" works for JAVA where "==" is a comparison operator in JAVA Dont the same apply for python???...

Answer (score 1):

A single equal sign, that is, `=`, is used for variable assignment.

For comparison, you must use double equals `==`. So replace your `if` line with this:

`if (b==False):`

In addition to this, the parentheses in Python are unnecessary. You could write:

`if b == False:`

And it would still work. Since `b` is a boolean value (True or False), you can also do

`if not b:`

Comment: But when it "=" works for JAVA where "==" is a comparison operator in JAVA Dont the same apply for python???...

Comment: @Anith I'm not very familiar with Java, but my guess is that assignment is a function that returns 0. Since 0 cast to a boolean is false, that's why your code works. It's not really expected behaviour, though. Try changin the condition to `if (b=true)` and see if it outputs the same thing. My guess is that it will.

Comment: @Anith for Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393988/getting-confused-with-and-in-if-statement .. `if(b=false)` evaluates to `if(b)` which is false

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig not really.. check my comment above

Answer (score 1):

`b` is already a boolean, there's no need to compare it to another boolean.

```
b = True
if not b:
    print("hello")
else:
    print("hi")
```

or simply reverse the logic:

```
b = True
if b:
    print("hi")
else:
    print("hello")
```

And if you did compare it to `False`, you'd write `b == False`, not `b = False`.

Finally, in Python, an assignment is a [statement, not an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869770/why-does-python-assignment-not-return-a-value). This was a deliberate choice, in order to avoid bugs when writing `if (b = x)` instead of `if (b == x)`.

Comment: But when it "=" works for JAVA where "==" is a comparison operator in JAVA Dont the same apply for python???...